# PL/SQL table level trigger running after second update

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have this problem whith this trigger which is calling a procedure updating a table after updating a row in other table.The problem is that you have to update table STAVKARACUNA two times to table RACUN update but it uses old values. Here is a code of both:

Here is a code of aa procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ukupnaCenaRacun (SIF IN VARCHAR2) AS
  SUMA float := 0;
  suma2 float := 0;
  Mesec NUMBER;
  popust float :=0.1;
BEGIN

  SELECT SUM(iznos) INTO SUMA
  FROM STAVKARACUNA
  WHERE SIF = SIFRARAC;

  SELECT SUM(vredrobe*pdv) INTO SUMA2
  FROM STAVKARACUNA
  WHERE SIF = SIFRARAC;

  SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATUM) INTO Mesec FROM RACUN WHERE SIF=SIFRARAC;

  IF(Mesec = 1) THEN
  UPDATE RACUN
  SET PDVIZNOS = SUMA2, ukupnozanaplatu = suma*(1-popust)
  WHERE SIFRARAC=SIF;
  END IF;

  IF (MESEC != 1) THEN
  UPDATE RACUN
  SET PDVIZNOS = SUMA2, ukupnozanaplatu = suma
  WHERE SIFRARAC=SIF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Here is a trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "UKUPNACENA_RACUN_UKUPNO" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OF CENA,KOL,PDV ON STAVKARACUNA
DECLARE 
  SIF VARCHAR2(20) := PACKAGE_STAVKARACUNA.SIFRARAC; 
BEGIN
  PACKAGE_STAVKARACUNA.ISKLJUCI_TRIGER('FORBID_UPDATING');
  ukupnaCenaRacun(SIF);
  PACKAGE_STAVKARACUNA.UKLJUCI_TRIGER('FORBID_UPDATING'); 
END;
```

The problem is when a table STAVKARACUNA is updated, nothing happens with table RACUN, but next time table STAVKARACUNA is updated the data in table RACUN is updated but with old values. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry,but hard to read, What is this SIF value?  That is what you are passing in to your procedure.  I don't see any reference to the trigger-level row values (:new, :old) being used.  looks like you are referencing some package-scoped variable (PACKAGE_STAVKARACUNA.SIFRARAC)  How do you know that is has the correct value?

Comment: SIF is value of identifier of RACUN on STAVKARACUNA. To be honest i don't know if it parses right value. How do you mean to use :new and :old values when it is table-level trigger.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware that a trigger for an event on a table should not directly access that table? The code is *inside* a DML event. The table is right in the middle of being altered in some say. So any query back to the same table could well attempt to read data that is in the process of being changed. It could try to read data that does not quite exist before a commit is performed or is one value now but will be a different value once a commit is performed. The table is *mutating*.

This goes for any code outside the trigger that the triggers calls. So the `ukupnaCenaRacun` procedure is executed in the context of the trigger. Yet it goes out and queries table `STAVKARACUNA` in two places (which can be placed in a single query but that is neither here nor there).

Since you're not getting a mutating table error, I can only assume that the update is not taking place until after the triggering event is committed but then you won't see the results until after *that* is committed sometime later -- like when the second update is committed.

That explanation actually sounds hollow to me as I have always thought that *all* activity performed by a trigger is committed or rolled back as part of one transaction. But that is the action you are describing.

It appears that `SIF` is a package variable defined in the package spec. Since everything in the procedure keys off that value and the trigger doesn't change the value, can't `SUMA` and `SUMA2` also be defined as variables, values to be updated whenever `SIF` changes?